# Is the 'Is' VB.NET keyword the same as Object.ReferenceEquals?

Tags: vb.net, operator-keyword, referenceequals

Is the `Is` VB.NET keyword the same as Object.ReferenceEquals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is, unless combined with a TypeOf check.

Quote from MSDN:

> The Is operator determines if two
>   object references refer to the same
>   object. However, it does not perform
>   value comparisons. If object1 and
>   object2 both refer to the exact same
>   object instance, result is True; if
>   they do not, result is False.
>
> Is can also be used with the TypeOf
>   keyword to make a TypeOf...Is
>   expression, which tests whether an
>   object variable is compatible with a
>   data type.

BTW, also note the IsNot operator (which gives the boolean inverse of the matching Is expression):

> IsNot is the opposite of the Is
>   operator. The advantage of IsNot is
>   that you can avoid awkward syntax with
>   Not and Is, which can be difficult to
>   read.